# How to debug/step into Qt sources from my project

Tags: qt, debugging, qt-creator

I want to debug, set break points, etc, in Qt sources,
I have Qt 5.5.0 built with symbols, and symbols are picked up, at least GDB says so.

But I still cannot debug into, for example, QGuiApplication, I want to be able to set break point anywhere in Qt sources and stop there when my code gets there.

I do have a Qt 5.5.0 project opened alongside with my project, but setting a break point in Qt 5.5.0 does not have any effect. Also, stepping into any Qt code simply does nothing, it just stays where it was stopped by a breakpoint in my project.

How can I place breakpoints anywhere in Qt?

I'm using: Ubuntu 14.04, Qt 5.5.0, Qt Creator 3.6.0, QNX (ARM platform).

Answer (score 0):

Don't install any Qt binary (qtcore/qtgui),

1. build from source;
2. install them with debug symbols, should be around 200~300M each library.
3. Make sure your example code is loading the debug version of Qt files.